# Variable in SQL not recognized despite using advice from many websites

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My knowledge of HTML and CSS is very good, but when it comes to PHP/SQL I knew ~0 until last week (developed multiple HTML/CSS-only websites) **In summary**: Hired experienced former business partner (I trusted this guy!) to develop site...Website looked great at first (I looked it over several times but never for hours at a time)...I paid my former partner for the work....recently have had time to REALLY REALLY scrutinize the website for hours at a time....have found MANY bugs....partner not responding to my help requests....I have to learn PHP to fix these bugs myself :)

Here's one of the issues: I need to retrieve one value (from a variable 'wealth' which all users have as part of their statistics) from an SQL database called 'stats' to ascertain if, for any given user, 'wealth' is (< 1) or (>= 1), but I cannot seem to retrieve this value. If wealth < 1, do **X**, but if wealth >= 1, do **Y**. Everything worked fine except **Y** executed for ANY value of wealth (including 0 and negative numbers). I tried to fix this by declaring a global variable  $stats9999 (I have also tried this as a local variable) which fetches the value from the SQL database, but this is where the problems start.  Here is the php code:

```
<?php session_start();

if ((($_SESSION['role']) != SHA1('user')) && (($_SESSION['status']) != SHA1('active')))       
{
header( 'Location: index.php' ) ;
session_destroy();
 } else 
include 'connect.php' ; //Connects to SQL database just fine

$_SESSION['fname'];
$_SESSION['login_id'];
$_SESSION['user'];

$stats9999=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT wealth FROM stats WHERE login_id = '"     
. mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['login_id']) . "'")); //Global $stats9999

if {.....} //Several if...else if statements in a row but no problems here as far as I 
//can tell, one of the problems is in next series of lines of code


else if  ((($_POST['hidden'] ) == 'Function') && (($stats9999) == 0)) {

    $message = 'Text1';

echo "<SCRIPT>
alert('$message');
location = 'profile.php';
</SCRIPT>"; 


            }

else if  ((($_POST['hidden'] ) == 'Function') && (($stats9999) != 0)) {

    $message = 'Text2';

echo "<SCRIPT>
alert('$message');
location = 'profile.php';
</SCRIPT>"; 


            }
```

The browser successfully recognizes "Function" and the site behaves appropriately if I do not try to account for 'wealth' via $stats9999. However, the problem is $stats9999 does not seem to be recognized. I am assuming the browser is somehow not "seeing/recognizing" the SQL database and/or database entry that I am querying for near the beginning of the code and/or not retrieving ("fetch"ing) the entry I want (I'm sure due to a mistake in my code). As an experiment, I have replaced ($stats9999 != 0) and ($stats9999 == 0) with ($_SESSION['user'] != " ") and ($_SESSION['user'] == " "). The code "sees/recognizes" these $_SESSION values as strings not equal to " ", and the site behaves in the appropriate way. This reinforces my belief the specific entry in the 'stats' database is not being "seen/recognized".

I have also tested $stats9999 by trying to echo '$stats9999' (plus variations of this name, wondering if this makes any difference but I think not) in the alert box, but in numerous variations have gotten various unwanted outcomes including (a) page crashes (b) blank alert box (c) resource id#2. With the code as written above, the site crashes.

I would greatly appreciate any help, and would be happy to clarify any confusing statements I have made....thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_assoc` returns an associative array, where the keys are the column names in the `select` query. You're trying to use `$stats9999` as if it's a scalar variable containing the column. You need to write:

```
$wealth = $stats9999['wealth'];
```

and then you can use `$wealth` in your `if` statements.

Comment: Thank you for your help Barmar; I changed my code before the first if statement to: $stats9999=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT wealth FROM stats WHERE login_id = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['login_id']) . "'"));

$wealth = $stats9999['wealth'];

Comment: The site is still crashing! I will continue to try and work on this.

Comment: You changed all the rest of the code to use `$wealth` instead of `$stats9999`, right?

Comment: Yes, I doublechecked and still, the site is crashing. I believe I understand what your code is suggesting and it sounds rational...in a nutshell, grab the 'wealth' value corresponding to the login_id of the current user, and use this value of wealth in the appropriate 'if' statement. I guess I will need to stare at this code until I get it right. One thing: is it a problem if I use connect.php both globally and locally. My guess is it should not matter. Thanks for your time! This site is great and was recommended by my brother.

Comment: Where should I add this code? print_r($stats9999)    Anywhere in the PHP section of the page or in a specific spot?

Comment: There was an output of: Array([wealth] => 6)

Comment: The number '6' from the print_r was from the 'wealth' the demo user had before the purchase was made.

Comment: Wait...it seems like it works now!! But to answer your question a lavender/blue background page appears, in which a white box displays in the top center which says "Server Error" with a frowning face on it; two buttons, Reload and More (I believe) are in the white box.

Comment: The error message is probably in the PHP log on the server, then.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Barmar.....your posts provided the expertise I was looking for on this site!